# Step Functions: Using a Pass State for basic logic

Tags: aws-step-functions

I have the following in my step function:
[image]

In the *INBOUND* Pass State, I have the following in the *Result*:

```
{
  "text.$": "$.message.text",
  "format": "html",
  "sourceLang.$": "$.thread.inbound_language",
  "targetLang.$": "$.account.primary_language"
}
```

In the *OUTBOUND* Pass State, I have the following in the *Result*:

```
{
  "text.$": "$.message.text",
  "format": "html",
  "sourceLang.$": "$.account.primary_language"
  "targetLang.$": "$.thread.inbound_language",
}
```

(the difference is slight: the values for target and source are switched)

Finally, in the ResultPath for both Pass States, I have:
`$.translationInstructions`

What's happening is that the *literal* Results are being added to the original input -- instead of the results of the path filters...

It's a very simple task and I don't want to have to create a lambda function to do this. Can I do this??

Comment: The actual result vs desired result is not clear.  Could you edit the question to clarify?

Comment: Sorry for the delay... Discovered that you can't do what I'm trying to do. I created a function to generate the appropriate instructions. (the difference is the source and target values are switched).